# jQuery and JSONP issues

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am trying to make the following jQuery AJAX JSONP request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: apiUrl + currentType + "/" + $(this).val() + "/" + nextType + ".json?jsoncallback=?",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(data))
    },
    error: function (reqObj, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(textStatus, error)
    }
});
```

The success function never runs and this is the logged data from the `error` function:

```
parsererror, message: "jQuery17205679343591909856_1334681898332 was not called"
```

I have no idea why this is not working...

Comment: Does the response correctly wrap the returned data in a function call?  (P.S. the `, null` is not necessary, you can remove it)

Comment: Yeah it does. I removed the `, null` as you suggested. It's still acting goofy :(

Comment: I am actually in the process of doing that now... I will report what happens

Comment: I have updated the code above to reflect the changes I have made

Comment: What is the text returned by the AJAX call? Can you eval it and confirm that it is valid javascript?

Comment: nothing is returned from the AJAX (well not in console.log; only if you look at the network tab in Chrome's debugger console will you see the returned JSON)

Comment: I figured it out! I will put my answer below

Answer (score 0):

So, after some configuration changes (on the API side), I was able to figure out my issue(s).

First, for quickly producing my JSON response on the API side, I was using the RABL gem for Rails. I included the configuration example in an initializer in the app (https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). *From Github:*

> If include_json_root is disabled that removes the root node for each
>   child in the output, and enable_json_callbacks enables support for
>   'jsonp' style callback output if the incoming request has a 'callback'
>   parameter.

Then, here is my jQuery (on the client consumer side):

```
$.ajax({
            url: apiUrl + currentType + "/" + $(this).val() + "/" + nextType + ".json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log('Success!');
            }
        });
```